# How I can convert data format in filehelpers c#

Tags: c#, filehelpers

I'm trying read this date 03/01/2020 00:17:41 from a .csv file, but when I try to convert to date with

```
[FieldConverter(ConverterKind.Date, "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss")]
public DateTime Field01_Fecha;
```

The log show me this error:

> FileHelpers.ConvertException: Error Converting '03/01/2020 00:17:41'
>   to type: 'DateTime'.  There are more chars in the Input String than in
>   the Format string: 'ddMMyyyy'

I tried with all date formats and none work for me.

Comment: Do you get the exception for this code or for different code? Format in exception doesn't match `FieldConverter` format.

Comment: I get exception for this code

Comment: Do you have another `DateTime` columns in the file? Can you reproduce the problem with file having only 1 column?

Comment: No, this is the only

Comment: Are you sure that your code compiles successfully? Is it possible that you execute file compiled using old code?

Answer (score 1):

This should work. The error message is the sort of message you would get without the proper FieldConverter.

The following is a simple test which works for me.

```
void Main()
{
    string sampleData = @"03/01/2020 00:17:41";

    var engine = new FileHelperEngine<Test>();
    var test = engine.ReadString(sampleData);

    Console.WriteLine(test[0].fldDateTime);  
}

[DelimitedRecord(",")]
private class Test
{
    [FieldConverter(ConverterKind.Date, "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss")]
    public DateTime fldDateTime;

}
```